# What is the best way to put back all entries in rte_mempool in one go

Tags: c, dpdk, rte, dpdk-pmd, ovs-dpdk

I am using a [mempool](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__mempool_8h.html) in my dpdk app to store values that are periodically emitted to an external server. Everytime the values are emitted I want to replenish the complete mempool. What is the best wat to put back all elements as available to the mempool?

Comment: Should you not be calling the `put` function that matches the `get` used to acquire the objects in the first place? Your other choice is to destroy the mempool and create a new one.

Comment: I am essentially looking for a put_all kind of function. What is the performance difference (theoretically superiror) doing a put to all elements one by one vs destroy/create? My mempool has 100k elements.